# Prevent additional redirects from .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I know this question has been asked a million times before in various formats, but I cannot seem to find an answer that helps me. I have a directory containing multiple subdirectories that are assigned to different 'clients'. I am attempting to protect these directories by using a .htaccess file in the main directory that routes all requests to a PHP login page. Simple enough, and it would work fine, except that when the login page attempts to redirect me to where I am supposed to be, I am again redirected to the login page. My simple script looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myloginpage.php [NC,L,QSA]
```

I just want to redirect only when a user is not logged in; ideally, I would set a session variable with the PHP to be checked by the .htaccess file that would indicate that the user has been authorized. However, sessions cannot be utilized in .htaccess files. I've read some things about setting environment variables, but it doesn't seem like my Apache server (which I cannot configure) has mod_env enabled. I have also read about the END flag, which might be nice - however my Apache version is not recent enough (2.2.31).

I am at a loss for a solution - I have tried everything that has occurred to me, so all help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem is that any PHP is run _after_ the .htaccess, and whatever you set in PHP, including environment variables, will be reset on the next request. The only thing that's persistent is Sessions but, as you your self pointed out, can't be utilized by .htaccess. .haccess can set environment variables for PHP, not the other way around.

Comment: What's in the sub directories? Files or code?

Comment: That illuminates the issue a bit, thanks.

I have files in these directories, basically websites.

Comment: Isn't those websites using code? Or are they static web sites? What you can do is to add a .htaccess in the root of each sub-site, setting a basic auth. It should work, unless it's sensitive stuff . Basic auth is sent in clear text between the client and server, but unless it's sensitive stuff, it usually is enough.

Comment: Sorry, yes. They are using code.

Comment: It it's in PHP, you can simply check if the session exists on those sites, and if not, redirect to the login form. No need to mess with htaccess, then.

Comment: That does sound like a valid solution but I am trying to do this with a single htaccess file to handle everything. Since these directories get added and removed often, I want to avoid any sort of boilerplate that must be added to them. Ideally the solution doesn't add any additional modification to the contents of the directories

Comment: Then use the htaccess and basic auth.